# Bash scripts for transversing directories and conditionally creating or renaming files

Tags: linux, bash, hugo

I'm in the middle of creating conversion scripts to move content to something [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/) can support. I'm still learning Bash, so I suspect there's some error in the logic of this section of code - it's defaulting to the last "elif" clause which simply creates a new _index.md by default rather than checking for any of the other clauses.

Any guidance pointing me in the right direction for debugging this would be appreciated!

```
for d in `find ${CONTENT?} -type d ! -name 'media' ! -name 'releases' ! -name 'css' ! -name 'img'`
do
  NAME=$(echo ${PWD##*/})
  # Does index.md exist?
  if [[ -f index.md ]]; then
    echo_info "A base file already exists; renaming to _index.md."
    mv ${d?}/index.md ${d?}/_index.md
  # Does _index.md exist?
  elif [[ -f _index.md ]]; then
    echo_info "_index.md already exists for the selected content directory."
  # Does a file exist with the same name as the directory?
  elif [[ -f ${NAME?}.md ]]; then
    echo_info "A base file already exists; renaming to _index.md."
    mv ${d?}/${NAME?}.md ${d?}/_index.md
  # If none of the above exist, default to creating a new _index.md.
  elif [[ ! -f index.md || ! -f _index.md || ! -f ${NAME?}.md ]]; then
    echo_info "Creating _index.md for directory."
    cd ${BUILD?} && hugo new ${d?}/_index.md
  fi
done
```

Comment: If you add a `set -x` to the top of the script, it will tell you the result of each evaluation. That might make it easier to spot the problem. I see that you are using `find` to look for directories. But you never `cd` to that directly. Wouldn't `NAME=$(echo ${PWD##*/})` always evaluate to the same thing?

Comment: Instead of using `${foo?}`  everywhere, maybe just `set -e` once? `-e` will make the script error out if any variable is unset.

Comment: @omajid Yes, I believe you're right. Still trying to think about how to do that part effectively, thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: I definitely recommend a quick read of http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/

Comment: Thank you!! Definitely will read into this.

Comment: [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't changing directory (`cd`) to the directory you're looping through. Thus the `-f` checks will all be in the current directory, which may not even be under `$CONTENT`.

All of your `-f` checks need to be done either with the current working directory set to the desired directory, or with a full path.  Probably just doing `if [[ -f ${d?}/index.md ]]; then` and likewise will suffice.

Comment: That was it. I was too in the weeds to realize, heh. Thank you! :)